# Uniqueness and exsistence of solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given ODE:  $u''(x) + u'(x) = f(x)$ and $u(0) = u'(0) = \frac{1}{2}[u(L) + u'(L)]$. Does a solution exist? Is it unique?
My attempt:
By using integrating factor, the general solution is given by $u(x) = \int_{0}^{x}(e^{-\zeta}(c_1 + \int_{0}^{\zeta}e^{\xi}f(\xi)d\xi))d\zeta + c_2$. So, can I say a solution exist? And I have no idea about uniqueness.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your problem is $\begin{cases} \ddot{u}+\dot{u}=f,\\ u(0)=a,\quad \dot{u}(0)=a, \end{cases}$ with $x\in [0,L]$. I think you should clarify that part. Then the IVP is a *linear* ODE with initial conditions $u(0)$ and $\dot{u}(0)$. Hence my question and hint is: do you know the theorems about the existence and uniqueness under this hypotheses behaviour?

Comment: Hi @Alex, actually I don't know any theorems for that.

Comment: Any hints anyone?

Comment: @new_stud Then you should look into those theorems